# Sequelize MySQL handling native reference errors in Queries (ManyToMany)

Tags: mysql, error-handling, sequelize.js, many-to-many

I am new to MySQL and Sequelize and try to implement an error handling for a many to many relation with a reference error. I have the following relation Post > CategoryPost < Category relation. The migration of my Joining Table looks like this

```
module.exports = {
   up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

    await queryInterface.createTable("CategoryPost", {
      CategoryId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        references: {
          model: "categories",
          key: "id",
        },
      },
      PostId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
},

 down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("CategoryPost");
  },
};
```

With the reference I try to prevent posts with non existing categories in my joining table. Which seems to work. Here is my CREATE POST Router incl. Controller.

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  let { userUuid, title, body, categories } = req.body;
  if (!categories) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Pls provide category" });
  }
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { uuid: userUuid } });
    const post = await Post.create({
      userId: user.id,
      title,
      body,
    });
    await post.addCategories(categories);
    return res.json(post);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong"});
  }
});
```

It works as expected.
But if i try to insert post with non existing category I got a very ugly "native" mysql error, which I struggle to handle in a good manner.

[image]

My goal is to send a correct error msg "Please provide post with valid category", if there is a undefined category

The only thing i can think of is to check against Category.find(all). But it feels like double implementing the native db functionality of a foreign key and causes extra requests.

Sorry for my English, I hope the question became clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `joining` table should have its own primary key not related to neither 'Post' foreign key nor `Category` one. That's one common way how many-to-many table should work in general. Unfortunately Sequelize does not support composite primary keys so it's useless to indicate both `CategoryId` and `PostId` as a primary key (that definitely might be the second way).

And also you forgot to indicate `PostId` as a foreign key to `posts`.

```
await queryInterface.createTable("CategoryPost", {
      Id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      CategoryId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "categories",
          key: "id",
        },
      },
      PostId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "posts",
          key: "id",
        },
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
},
```

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, thank you for your help. The code looks much better than mine :-). Unfortunately this doesn't change the situation with the error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is there a special way or library for handling these kind of errors that you as an expert would recommend?

Comment: Did you recreated a table?

Comment: Yes Sir, recreated with two foreign keys. I used your code. But If I get your code right, the error is totally expected? If I try to create a post and provide a non existant category then the db says ERR. I am sorry to be such a noob. Thank you for your help anyways.

Comment: Wait! What did you plan to do by calling `await post.addCategories(categories);`? To create new categories and link them to a post OR to link existing categories to a post?

Comment: Oh no, sorry for being not precise enough. I just plan to give the post a (predefind) category. And I don't want anywone who creates a new post can add a category on the fly. And if someone create a post with a not existing category the api should give the answer -> Please provide a valid category. I am not able to give an appropriate json response in this scenario. Sorry for my English and once more thank you for comming back to this.

Comment: Did you check all category ids listed in `categories ` exists in DB?

Comment: Hi Anatoly. My seeder contains Three Categories with CategorieID 1, 2, 3. If I provide the categories through req.body.categories as an array which contains only numbers between 1, 2, 3 everything works without an error and the post get saved. But if someone would give an category array of [1, 2, 45] the error comes up. The api returns 500 "Something went wrong". The state should be not 500 ist should be a 4er state with a message. "Please provide valid categories". Anyway. Thanks a million.

Comment: You just need to check `categories` against DB before trying to link them with a post.

Comment: Thanks a million. This is the way I will handle this for the future. My hope was to prevent this extra call to the db. Thank you for your invaluable help and your patience.